# Rotation using Bilinear Interpolation Backward Mapping Calculation?

Tags: image-processing, bilinear-interpolation

I just started learning Image processing.
Could someone help me explain this [Step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxYkp.png) how to calculate these column? i really don't understand it. So please explain it simply as possible.

Rotation formula -> [forward and backward mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvHdF.png)

Flowchart diagram and equations [Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qvZP.png)

Forward mapping -> [Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCilR.png)

Backward mapping table1 [Step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHohc.png)  <-- here is my question

Backward mapping table1(cont.) -> [Step4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd3y3.png)

Forward mapping and Backward mapping result -> [Step5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtUZw.png)

Comment: It would be good if you could add more context to your question. The table needs context to understand what the symbols and variables mean.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I added all information into steps and that's all the information i have, Hope this helps.